# Rolling out updates or letting user to upgrade to paid version VS SQLite data preservation C# UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, upgrade, updates

I have a general question.

I'm still in developing mode and I need to decide on best solution.

I am planning to rollout two apps for UWP - Free and Paid versions.

I am also developing remotely hosted API to migrate user SQLite data into the "cloud"(server end MySQL).

At first, I want to rollout Free version of the app and let user to "upgrade" to the paid version.

I believe that best solution will be to offer Paid version as an upgrade, and migrate all data via server API.

That would mean the Free version must be ready for data "Backup" before the upgrade is done.

Or is there a way to preserve UWP database file upon the upgrade?

Please correct me if I'm wrong and I will appreciate any help from people who will put me in the right direction.

Preferably I would like to use Subscription Add-On to my Free App.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you actuality want two apps or do you want to have a "freemium" app that's free with an in-app purchase to unlock more features?

Comment: Good point. I read on Microsoft that best choice would be to do one app with in-app purchases that will unlock the paid feature